# Can we Rollback kafka message

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In My Java Application, I am connecting to 2 different Kafka Clusters (say C1 and C2),
Currently I publish the same message to both of these clusters(C1 and C2), like below:

```
firstKafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
secondKafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
```

I want to publish the message in some transactional way so that when message published to C1, then if the
publishing failed to C2, then the message should also not be published to the C1, It should be be rollbacked somehow? Can we achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Add a consumer that reads the message within a timeperiod?

Comment: how will that help?

Comment: If the consumer does not read the message it is not delivered to the topic. But re-reading the question it looks like you want to perform the write around the same time and want to remove the message if either fails.

Comment: If you're using two clusters, this type of "spanning transaction" isn't possible. Kafka records cannot be rolled back after produced and acknowledged. You could build in logic to your consumers to lookup offsets externally and skip any events that match some conditions, though

Comment: since i do not have the control of consumer applications. that is why i was looking for something that I can do at my end, if there is a way I can undo the sendMessage, abort the transaction so that the message will not be published

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not support distributed transactions (a.k.a. XA transactions) so you cannot simply write to both clusters in one big transaction and be able to roll it back.

If you do not want to change your consumers at all, you can consider writing only to the first cluster, and use [MirrorMaker](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-summit-2020/getting-up-to-speed-with-mirrormaker-2/) or a similar tool to copy the messages from one topic to the next. If the second cluster fails to write the message, MirrorMaker will retry until the message can be written.

You can also consider monitoring the second cluster and disabling message producing to the first cluster if the second one is unable to receive messages.